# How can you sort a JSON object efficiently using JQ

Tags: json, sorting, key, jq

I've got JSON in the format

```
{
  "a": {
    "size":3
  },
  "b": {
    "size":2
  },
  "c": {
    "size":1
  }
}
```

I need to sort it by size, e.g.:

```
{
  "c": {
    "size": 1
  },
  "b": {
    "size": 2
  },
  "a": {
    "size": 3
  }
}
```

I have found a way to do it, e.g.:

```
. as $in | keys_unsorted | map ({"key": ., "size" : $in[.].size}) | sort_by(.size) | map(.key | {(.) : $in[.]}) | add
```

but this seems quite complex so I'm hoping there's a simpler way that I've overlooked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `to_entries` / `from_entries`, like this:

```
jq 'to_entries|sort_by(.value.size)|from_entries' file.json
```

`to_entries` will transform your input object into a list of `key`/`value` pair objects:

```
[
  {
    "key": "a",
    "value": {
      "size": 3
    }
  },
  ...
  {
    "key": "c",
    "value": {
      "size": 1
    }
  }
]
```

That allows to apply `sort_by(.value.size)` to that list and then convert it back to an object using `from_entries`.